# Array sorting case-sensitivity

Tags: php, sorting

I'm just wondering why the    ksort() function sorts uppercase keys first and then lowercase keys by default?

What is the logic beyond this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

uppercase value smaller than lowercase values.

eg:- in ascii. A - 65, a - 97

Answer (score 13):

It seems you're familiar with the fact that `ksort()` is case sensitive.

The reason is unclear to me, but there's an easy solution.

`uksort()` allows you to sort an array with an user-defined function, however, lazy as we are, we don't want to define our own function and use a native one. The function `strcasecmp()` allows us to compare a string in an case-insensitive way and works the very same way when we would define our own function. When a string has a high value, a value bigger than 0 is returned. If the value is smaller, a smaller value is returned and if it's equal, the function returns 0. So, a perfect candidate for our `uksort()` function.

This will work for you: `$sorted = uksort($array, 'strcasecmp');`

Comment: I was not looking for a solution (I uppercased my keys actually) but I was asking my self "What's the logic?" ;)

Comment: Well that's pretty easy! `ksort()` uses `SORT_REGULAR` as sort flag on default. This flag sorts the characters using the character ascii code where upper-case characters have a lower value than the lower-case characters as can be seen [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_ascii.asp). That explains why!

Comment: sometimes `strnatcasecmp()` sorts even better. For me the best solution was `uksort($array, 'strnatcasecmp');`

Answer (score 2):

Because uppercase letters are "higher" that lowercase letters when ordering letters, punctuation is higher again. It goes A-Za-z.

For a natural case insensitive sort use `natcasesort($array);`.

Comment: He's trying to sort on key, not on value.

Answer (score 0):

Found this question searching for a solution to my problem of 'wrong' sorting done by ksort. I answered to myself "Well, this is the way ksort meant to be". And my solution is:

```
ksort($array, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE)
```

with these flags it will put 'Payment' after 'password', not before.